# Opensource site statistics for PHP

Tags: php, open-source, piwik

I am looking a modern, PHP based visitor statistics tracker. As mentioned in the title it must be open source. The other features it must contain are referrer tracking, no of unique hit by daily, monthly etc, with reports.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I rewrote the entire question to make it readable. I don't think I changed any of the content.

Comment: Please rewrite my question

Comment: but referer links now showing

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712467/minimalistic-visitor-stats-based-on-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For local installation using PHP, there's [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) which is - at least a little bit - aspiring to be a Google Analytics clone. The interface looks nice, and it's under continuous development.

Comment: yes piwik is really fine, 

Assume if i used this piwik , is there any chance,piwik track my site, That is How much this is secure..but i installed in local its really very nice..

Answer (score 2):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/)

Comment: I was looking for a localhost based alternative to GA too. This looks great. And it's pluggable.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution you'll find is [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics). Now it's not "open source" (why does it need to be?), so you may be interested in setting up something that parses your local log files, like [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: we have google analatic already,

Comment: Google Analytics is not open source. It's free, but not open source.

Comment: Bharanikumar, why do you need something more than Google Analytics? It does everything already. @John I know it's not open source, I said that in my answer :)

Comment: no my google analatic is much more enough, but am looking some graphic type of charts and all..

Comment: Google Analytics has API, so you export all data and therefore there is no need to use any open source solution.

Comment: Analytics does graphics and charts...better than most other options I've seen :)

Comment: You were editing while I was commenting. ;)

Comment: @John: Ah, my apologies :)

Answer (score 1):

AWstats [link text](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is free and open source and arguably the best server side stats available.

Comment: Why was this post edited? Nothing changed.

Comment: @John : if you click on the time next to "edited", you have access to the history of your answer, showing what's been modified for each edit ;; it'll show you the link was not perfect when you posted (the link is on "link text", and not on "AWstats"), then Sam152 corrected it, and you rolled-back to the first version, cancelling the correction done by Sam152.